# PushScreen to a screen from jar file

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, jar

I have created a jar file of few of my classes and preverified them too in blackberry. Now I have imported them successfully in another project. However, when I create a new project and import it, I want to pushScreen to a screen class which is present in one of those jar files. But everytime it opens my current project screen. I want know whether it is possible to pushscreen to a jar class or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself. The jar file was not properly preverified. After I preverified all over again and imported the jar, I could push screen to the jar file's screen class. I created a button in my current project & on click, i pushed it to Mainscreen of Jar file. It worked.